# Issue installing Java EE 7 SDK update 1

Tags: mac, bash, installation, osx-yosemite, java-web-start

I've installed `Java (jdk 1.8)` and set `JAVA_HOME`, now I'm trying to install `Java EE 7 SDK` which I downloaded it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-downloads-1956236.html). The Oracle download page shows `Universal Zip Installer` type file, downloaded and extracted it. As per the instructions in `readme` file.

> To start GlassFish, just go in the directory where GlassFish is
>   located and type:
>
> ```
>        On Unix: glassfish4/glassfish/bin asadmin start-domain
> ```

On executing the command, bash returned an error as follows:

```
bash: glassfish4/glassfish/bin: is a directory
```

I was completely skeptic with the `Universal Zip Installer` file, as I was watching few tutorials where I found `.sh` file for installing `Java EE`.

So, somehow I found the link to download the file in [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-jdk-7u21-downloads-1956231.html), downloaded the `.sh` file and tried to execute it using the commands.

> ./java_filename.sh

returned  `bash: permission denied message`

> sudo -s java_filename.sh
>
> sudo ./java_filename.sh

returned `bash: Command not found`

I'm using `OS X` `Yosemite 10.10,` did any one come across this kind of issue? If so, how to install Java EE 7 (with glassfish server).

Comment: @Ramhound 1.8 is JDK version not the EE